# How can i import data from kaggle while not downloading it?

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I want to import data from kaggle to my Notebook while not having to download it (So if i share my .ipynb u only need to run the code and it will download it from the internet), but i can't figure out if it is even possible and which link to copy. Here is the kaggle website:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kukuroo3/body-performance-data/data?select=bodyPerformance.csv

```
data = pd.read_csv('link here')
```

I tried copying the download button link, but it doesn't work and says: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 2

Comment: Most likely no, you need an account to download from this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1st method

you can head into the dataset page and click on new notebook at the top right corner
[image]

## 2nd method

open any notebook and click on add data at the right menue

[image]

## 3rd method

*not recommended, since each person that opens the ipynb will have to upload their own token first.*

when using colab first download your kaggke json key and do the following steps

- create a kaggle key, you can go into your settings then head into the account tab and you can find a `create new token` button in the api section, click on it to download your token.
  [image]
- install the kaggle library

```
! pip install  kaggle
```

- upload your kaggle key or you can put the following code to upload the key

```py
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

- now you can download your dataset using the following code

```py
!kaggle datasets download -d [user/data-name]
```

in our example here `[user/data-name]` is `kukuroo3/body-performance-data`

[image]

Comment: So in any case you need an account, no? Either to use the builtin notebook (which is not really what was asked) or to download the file with the API.